# how to use angularjs in clojure luminus

Tags: angularjs, clojure, luminus

I want to use angularjs in clojure luminus templates.
below is my code in luminus.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="">
      <p>Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
      <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
```

but not getting {{name}} value.
please help me how to solve this issue.thanks in advance!

Comment: I think its perfect. provide more info about your issue.

Comment: i am not getting the value of name, {{name}} is empty,

Comment: Approve my edit and check it.

Comment: you are runing in outside {block} but i need it inside clojure-luminus {block}.

Comment: if i make it sample. how clojure-lumius differentiate with luminus tags and angularjs tags.because both are using same tags {{}}..

Answer (score 1):

By default luminus is using [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer)  template system. Selmer - gives you an option to redefine `:tag-open :tag-close :filter-open :filter-close` tags.

So if you change your render function to be something like this:

```
(defn render
  "renders the HTML template located relative to resources/templates"
  [template & [params]]
  (content-type
 (ok
  (parser/render-file
    template
    (assoc params
      :page template
      :csrf-token *anti-forgery-token*
      :servlet-context *app-context*) {:tag-open \[ :tag-close \] :filter-open \[ :filter-close \[}))
"text/html; charset=utf-8"))
```

You will be able to use angular tags, but you will have to replace all Selmer tags with `[% %]`.
Also, you can use what ever you want as open/close tag. Foe example `<` and `>`